# Is there a way to speed this up? (max-pooling)

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, max

This is the code:

```
A = rand(3,3,3);

P(1) = max(max(A(:,:,1)));
P(2) = max(max(A(:,:,2)));
P(3) = max(max(A(:,:,3)));
```

Comment: how about `P = max(max(A,[],3));` ?

Comment: In which dimension you want the max-values in `P` after execution? Without initialization it would be the second like `size(P) --> [1 3]`.

Comment: @Matt: You are right, missed that part. If dimensions of P matter, a `reshape` or `squeeze` is necessary in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create P in one call:

```
%fastest solution for size(A,1)>size(A,2)
P = max(max(A,[],1),[],2)

%fastest solution for size(A,2)>size(A,1)
P = max(max(A,[],2),[],1)
```

For large matrices, it is faster to have a small intermediate result (the output of the first max call)

Comment: `size(A,1)` always equals to `size(A,2)` in my problem

Comment: Then it does not matter which one you chose.

Comment: I accidentally noticed a strange thing, yes your code takes 6% less time to execute but if I put my code in a single line like this `P(1) = ... ; P(2) = ... ; P(3) = ... ;` it's also 6% faster.

Comment: Please share your benchmarking code with us, there is probably something wrong with it. Did you run your code repeatedly? Matlab JIT Compiler sometimes slows down the first execution causing strange results.

Comment: your one call method is indeed better for the example provided above, but when I add one more index and loop it the single line version of the original is faster, that is weird as hell! Run this with 'Run and Time'....
main: [link](http://textuploader.com/aao85)
functions: [link](http://textuploader.com/aao8d) ... Take into account that P will actually have two more indices! LOL

Comment: Performance heavily depends on the input size. What matrix size did you use?

Comment: `A = rand(3,3,3,16);` .... I provided all the code in links, try running it yourself you'll be amazed that placing commands on a single line can speed up the performance!

Comment: Okay, I expected A to be an example for a larger matrix. With such low execution times minimal differences can cause such behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to collapse first two dimensions into one, and maximize along that dimension. I haven't tested it for speed, though.

```
P = max(reshape(A,[],size(A,3)));
```